# how to read all values from file and generate related responses using restful webservices

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat

In client class i have hardcoded  int inch=12;   int feet=2; but my requirement is that  have to 
create separate file having several inch's and feets..i want to get all inch and feet values from 
file and their related responses.

my client code:
    public class TempClient {

```
    static final String REST_URI = "http://localhost:8081/CustomerDemo";  

    static final String INCH_TO_FEET = "/ConversionService/InchToFeet/";  

    static final String FEET_TO_INCH = "/ConversionService/FeetToInch/";


    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        int inch=12; 

        int feet=2;

        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();  

        Client client = Client.create(config);

        WebResource service = client.resource(REST_URI); 


        WebResource addService = service.path("rest").path(INCH_TO_FEET+inch); 

        System.out.println("INCH_TO_FEET Response: " + getResponse(addService)); 

        System.out.println("INCH_TO_FEET Output as XML: " + getOutputAsXML(addService)); 

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");


        WebResource subService = service.path("rest").path(FEET_TO_INCH+feet); 

        System.out.println("FEET_TO_INCH Response: " + getResponse(subService)); 

        System.out.println("FEET_TO_INCH Output as XML: " + getOutputAsXML(subService)); 

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");


    }  

    private static String getResponse(WebResource service) {  

        return service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(ClientResponse.class).toString(); 

    }  

    private static String getOutputAsXML(WebResource service) { 

        return service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class); 

    }  
}
```

Comment: So, you're asking us how to read a file, right? Google for "Java IO tutorial", click on the first link, read, and try something.

Answer (score 0):

supposing you have a file called data.txt like

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

you can do something like

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\Leo\\workspace\\STackOverflow\\src\\data.txt")));
    String line = null;
    List<Integer> inches = new ArrayList<Integer>();        
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
        inches.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
    }
    br.close();

    for(Integer inch:inches){
        WebResource addService = service.path("rest").path(INCH_TO_FEET+inch); 
        System.out.println("INCH_TO_FEET Response: " + getResponse(addService)); 
        System.out.println("INCH_TO_FEET Output as XML: " + getOutputAsXML(addService)); 
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
    }
```

then you can do the same for feet